# How to add arguments to links in gnome-shell menu

Tags: gnome-shell

I'm using gnome-shell with Ubuntu 11.10. At the left edge there is menu with icons. Where can I edit the command that is launched after clicking them? For example, there is gvim icon and I want it to start with -geometry flag. I assume it is in some config file, but where?

Answer (score 5):

To add startup arguments you have to modify the Exec parameter of the .desktop file. The gvim.desktop file is in

```
/usr/share/applications/gvim.desktop
```

Add the arguments you need to the line.

```
Exec=gvim -f %F
```

This will affect all users on your system. If you want a custom launcher file you can create a .desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications.

Comment: If you have to use arguments with two signals, like: myapp --disable-gpu, you should use quotes:   myapp "--disable-gpu"